# format string used in printf function in C programming

Tags: c, printf

In this code:

```
sprint(buf_ptr, "%.*s", MAX_BUF_LEN, desc);
```

what does `"%.*s",` mean?  what does `"%20.20s"` and  `"%.28s"` mean- in `snprintf`?

Comment: In `printf` formatting a period `.` followed by a number is the "precision", which for strings means the maximum number of bytes printed. A `*` instead of a number for either precision or field width means that the number is read from an argument.

Comment: would you mind, could you give me example, to get clear picture?  i define the size of MAX_BUF_LEN is 60. 
``# define MAX_BUF_LEN 60``,  so how %20.20s  and %.28s will do in snprintf?

Comment: Look up the documentation for `printf`, examples are plentiful

Comment: The "%20.20s" format will print a string with an output field 'width' of **exactly** 20 characters: adding leading spaces if the string is shorter than 20, truncating (from the right) if it has more than 20.

Answer (score 2):

In the `%*s` format specification, the `s` indicates that the argument will be a (null-terminated) character string and the `*` (width specifier) says that the field width is given as the argument ***immediately preceding*** the string.

In your other examples, the width specifier(s) is(are) given as fixed values.

Actually, in the `printf` formats you give, there are both ***width*** and ***precision*** specifiers: the *width* is the value before the period and the *precision* is after. For strings, the *width* is the minimum output field size (space padded if necessary) and the precision is the maximum number of characters to print (string will be truncated, if necessary). In either case, if a `*` is specified for either, it will be assumed to be in the list of arguments (as an integer) immediately before the string it applies to.

Comment: When a _precision_ is given, the null character is not necessary.

Comment: @chux Not necessary ***only*** if the string array has more characters than the given precision. Otherwise, you can expect garbled garbage output.

Answer (score 1):

> what does "%.*s", mean?

`desc`, below, is a *character pointer* that need not point to a *string*<sup>1</sup>.  Printing will continue until `MAX_BUF_LEN` charters (the *precision*)  are printed or until a *null character* is read - which ever comes first.

```
sprint(buf_ptr, "%.*s", MAX_BUF_LEN, desc);
```

> what does "%20.20s" ...  mean- in snprintf?

Let us use two different values for clarity: `"%19.21s"`.

`desc` is a *character pointer* that need not be a *string*.  Printing will continue until `21` charters are printed or until a *null character* is read - which ever comes first.  If the the number of charters to print is less than 19 (the *minimum width*), pad on the left with spaces to make at least 19 characters total.

```
sprint(buf_ptr, "%19.21s", desc);
```

> what does ... "%.28s" mean- in snprintf?

Just like `sprint(buf_ptr, "%.*s", 28, desc);`

---

Loosely speaking, think of `"%minimum.maximum s"`

---

<sup>1</sup>  A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.